# Regular expression to fetch the value within all the " "

Tags: ruby, regex

```
a='fdkfjsdflksdj lfkjdflksdjf["fdkljfdfl"]fkjdfldjkf["fdfdf"]dfdfsdfsdfsdfddfdfkdfj["fdfds"]fdfasdfds'
```

I need to fetch the values which is inside `""` that means out put should be

```
fdkljfdfl
fdfdf
fdfds
```

I have written the below coding

```
puts a[/\["(.*)"\]/m]
```

but it returns

```
["fdkljfdfl"]fkjdfldjkf["fdfdf"]dfdfsdfsdfsdfddfdfkdfj["fdfds"]
```

Can you help me to take that particular string within `""`

Comment: Is your keyboard broken?

Comment: There's no point in obfuscating example code. Use readable placeholders like "foo bar baz" or "abc def ghi" instead.

Comment: I agree, it is easier to read an example with foobar bizbaz. Furthermore, it seems like bracket are always around quotation marks. You may want to test out further with Rubular.com

Comment: @Stefan Ok, I would give some meaningful string hereafter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts a.scan(/\["(.*?)"\]/m)

              ^^
```

Make your regex non greedy.Or use negation based regex.

```
puts a.scan(/\["([^"]*)"\]/m)
```

Comment: but it's not displaying all the words within ""  instead it displays the first "" that is "fdkljfdfl"

Comment: hi but it says 'unknown regexp option - g'

Comment: Yes , scan is working, thanks, but this is throwing the following error puts a[/\["(.*?)"\]/gm] 

unknown regexp option - g

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a.scan(/"([^"]*)"/).flatten
#=> ["fdkljfdfl", "fdfdf", "fdfds"]
```

it will return the array of string